# CTRL+C to Webbrick server ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the past, I could exit my rails application launched using webbrick using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. At some point in development, this functionality broke ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> does nothing now). I'm lead to believe this was caused by changes in one of my gem dependencies, as the problem is also present when checking out a really old version of the application, using the current gemset.

My question is: how can I fix this problem, or at least find the out what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have solved my own problem. Authlogic

```
gem "authlogic", :git => 'http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git'
```

appears to be the root cause of this problem. I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/246)

Comment: dear , it was not the solution / answer of your question , i think you should some one else post with higher votes , which lead to actual solution to you answer .

Answer (score 10):

For windows users, this was broken in more recent builds of rails (3.2+). Try using

```
ruby script\rails server
```

instead.   More details [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5360).

Comment: Works great, even on laptops that don't have a pause or break key.

Answer (score 9):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>. It should work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with an application. It would seem that the issue is not with the authlogic gem but with the ":git" option. My entry causing webrick & mongrel to stop responding to Ctrl+C was

```
gem 'globalize3', :git => 'git://github.com/refinerycms/globalize3.git'
```

Comment: I just started having this problem with my system, getting paperclip from its :git source.  I commented out the :git and it's working just fine. Upvote for giving specifics of the problem.

Comment: Look at this question [#6086601](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086601/using-ubuntu-11-04-i-cant-shut-down-rails-server-using-ctrl-c/6109606#6109606) for a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Interesting experience (and good workaround for the next weeks):

If you are under Ubuntu and use Guake for quick terminal access, you can launch

```
rails s
```

there. Ctrl + C reproducibly works there for me and stops the server.

Hope I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing similar issues, specifically on Ubuntu 11.04 (things were fine on 10.04).  I've created another question that was more specific to my particular setup, but it sounds like there is a lot of crossover, so people might be interested in reading it as well:
[Can't stop WEBrick 1.3.1 with ctrl-c on Ubuntu 11.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891567/292045)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem on Ubuntu 11.04, Ruby 1.9.2p290. This fixed it for me:

Remove all existing Ruby & Ruby-related packages

Install [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/)

Install Ruby 1.9.3

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Make sure it works

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [x86_64-linux]
```

Install all your gems, etc...

Answer (score 0):

why not trap()ing signals?
http://theriyanto.wordpress.com/2006/04/05/develop-a-simple-webserver-using-webrick/