# Stopping rails server doesn't kill process

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal

Every time I stop my rails server with CTRL-Z, the process keeps running and I **always** have to kill -9 it in order to start the server again.

How can I make sure that the process is killed when I stop the server?

Comment: ctrl+z => suspend the process, and `fg` to resume it. So try to send SIGINT signal(Ctrl +C / kill -2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't stop WEBrick 1.3.1 with ctrl-c on Ubuntu 11.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891567/cant-stop-webrick-1-3-1-with-ctrl-c-on-ubuntu-11-04)

Comment: Oof, I feel very small (and dumb) right now. CTRl-C works fine. Thanks, saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop your server always so that there is no need for using `kill -9` to kill the process

Answer (score 0):

use `CRTL + C` short key to stop the rails server, than there will be no need to use `kill 9` every time.